# Hibernate many-to-one annotation and error on delete

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

I've this bean with annotations (showing the relevant ones):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Prodotti")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Prodotto {
    int id;
    String codice;
    double prezzo;
    double prezzoCanone;
    String descrizione;
    String note;

    Prodotto prodottoDiRiferimento;

...

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public Prodotto getProdottoDiRiferimento() {
        return prodottoDiRiferimento;
    }

    public void setProdottoDiRiferimento(Prodotto prodottoDiRiferimento) {
        this.prodottoDiRiferimento = prodottoDiRiferimento;
    }


}
```

all mapped to mySQL.

If I do a delete of one of these beans that has a prodottoDiRiferimento property set to null and that other beans have as they prodottoDiRiferimento, I get:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`jacciseweb`.`prodotti`, CONSTRAINT `FKC803BB11ACD3B812` FOREIGN KEY (`prodottoDiRiferimento_ID`) REFERENCES `prodotti` (`ID`))
```

What I'd like is that all the beans that point to the deleted one with the prodottoDiRiferimento property would get deleted too.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the inverse @OneToMany relationship declared as

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "prodottoDiRiferimento", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
```

If you do all you should need to do is remove the parent and the children should all be removed.